# PostgreSQL 9.6.1 Add new entry to pg_ts_config

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Currently the below query gives me only one result, I need english to be included as well.

```
 select * from pg_ts_config;
"simple";11;10;3722
```

I also need English in the list to create a full text search on a table.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html try `CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION ...`

Comment: CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION name (
    PARSER = parser_name |
    COPY = source_config
) 
What could be the parser_name here corresponding to english

Comment: postgres=> CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION eng_ts (parser=english);
ERROR:  text search parser "english" does not exist

I tried few valid parsers such as 'asciiword' & 'word' , but no hope

Comment: sorry - my bad. what is the output of `CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION try (copy=simple);`

Comment: How did you lose all the other entries in `pg_ts_config`?

Comment: This is a success
postgres=> CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION try (copy=simple);
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION
postgres=> \dF
     List of text search configurations
   Schema   |  Name  |     Description      
------------+--------+----------------------
 pg_catalog | simple | simple configuration
 public     | try    | 
(2 rows)

Question is how to we add english parser to it..

Comment: This is google cloud SQL instance.. This is a fresh installation

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation from google cloud SQl for Postgres Beta release. More TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATIONS are awaited in coming releases. 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-discuss/oK6aWw2nHOo